# How to use the Vaadin Testbench with Rich Text Area?

Tags: vaadin7

I am using Vaadin Testbench (4.1.0-alpha) for designing some integration test for my application (designed in Vaadin 7.6.1).

In a window, I use a rich test area. The idea is to design a test where the value of this rich text element is changed simulating some user behaviour. But now I realize I cannot find any method for change the value of this element, neither get the current value of the element.

I have tested some methods.`getHTML()` gets the HTML for the component, no the HTML of the designer. `getText()` gets the list of elements (font colour, background and other options of the element, but not the content).

Then I expect to have specific class methods for retrieving the value. If I explore the class RichTextAreaElement, seems that no method is implemented. All code in this class is:

```
@ServerClass("com.vaadin.ui.RichTextArea")
  public class RichTextAreaElement extends AbstractFieldElement {
}
```

As you can see, no method is declared.

How can I do a test where a user change the value of this rich text area? It is not implemented?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end, I was able to obtain the content of the element selecting the first `iframe` of the page, and searching for the `body` content. The final code looks like:

```
String currentWindow = getDriver().getWindowHandle();         
getDriver().switchTo().frame(getDriver().findElement(By.tagName("iframe")));
WebElement webelement = this.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body"));
String text = webelement.getText();
getDriver().switchTo().window(currentWindow);
return text;
```

As I need to switch between the `iframe` and the window, I am only able to obtain the content of the element, not the element itself. If I return directly the element for future use, an `org.openqa.selenium.StaleElementReferenceException: Element belongs to a different frame than the current one - switch to its containing frame to use it` exception is obtained.

For changing the text, the solutions is very similar, only use the sendKey functions to first remove existing characters and later add the new text:

```
String currentWindow = getDriver().getWindowHandle();
getDriver().switchTo().frame(getDriver().findElement(By.tagName("iframe")));
WebElement webelement = this.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body"));
// Remove any previous text.
String previousText = webelement.getText();
for (int i = 0; i < previousText.length(); i++) {
    webelement.sendKeys(Keys.DELETE);
}
// Set text.
webelement.sendKeys(text);
getDriver().switchTo().window(currentWindow);
```

Answer (score 0):

Hmm yeah, that looks like some work in progress, probably because it's a complex component with all the features it provides. Nonetheless we can workaround the limitations a bit, again making use of [chrome developer tools](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools) (or similar) and some custom classes to select the components by (actually it's just the `gwt-RichTextArea`).

Of course this serves just as a starting point and can be further enhanced. Also I'd be very interested to see a more elegant solution if someone finds one...

**Structure inspection**

[image: Component structure]

**Test class**

```java
public class RichTextAreaTest extends TestBenchTestCase {

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "D:\\Kit\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");
        setDriver(new ChromeDriver());
    }

    @After
    public void tearDown() throws Exception {
        // TODO uncomment below once everything works as expected
        //getDriver().quit();
    }

    @Test
    public void shouldModifyRichTextArea() throws InterruptedException {
        // class to identify the editor area by
        String editorClass = "gwt-RichTextArea";

        // open the browser
        getDriver().get("http://localhost:8080/");

        // select the first rich text
        RichTextAreaElement richTextArea = $(RichTextAreaElement.class).first();

        // get the editor section which is where we're writing
        WebElement richTextEditorArea = richTextArea.findElement(By.className(editorClass));

        // click inside to make it "editable"
        richTextEditorArea.click();

        // send some keystrokes
        richTextEditorArea.sendKeys(" + something else added by selenium");
    }
}
```

**Result:**

[image: Result]

---

**Update for getting the value**

If you simply want to get the text, the code below will do the trick:

```
// switch to the editor iframe
getDriver().switchTo().frame(richTextEditorArea);

// get the <body> section where the text is inserted, and print its text    
System.out.println("Text =[" + findElement(By.xpath("/html/body")).getText() + "]");
```

Output

> Text =[Some predefined text + something else added by selenium]

Comment: Still `richTextEditorArea.getText()` is failing. Returns always empty string. This webelement has Inside an html structure with desired text in the body, but from a WebElement I have no idea how to retrieve it.

Comment: @JorgeHortelano that's because its structure is complex with and iframe and a lot of other stuff to be able to provide rich text formatting. Although it may look similar to the `TextArea` component it's very different. Give me some time to see if I can find a workaround. Nonetheless the _text_ you're looking for is most likely some HTML content with formatting and the likes...

Comment: @JorgeHortelano see the bottom section of the response with the update on how to get the text. I wanted to try formatting it and see what the content is in that case but I did not get it in one shot and I'm busy with something else atm. Cheers